# how to avoid automatic sorting with seaborn in a grid plot? (python)

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to plot some data I have and I'm strugling with automatic sorting by seaborn. As you can see in the image bellow, each graph has a different sorting for the x-axis, I would like them to be the same, [Melhorou, Piorou, Indiferente]. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Here's my piece of code with what I've done so far.

[image]

```
f = plt.figure()

ax = f.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
sns.despine(f)
sns.histplot(data = data , x = "A pandemia afetou a sua performance acadêmica?  [1o sem de 2020]", multiple="dodge", palette = "Blues", ax = ax);
plt.xlabel("1o sem 2020")

ax = f.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
sns.despine(f)
sns.histplot(data = data , x = "A pandemia afetou a sua performance acadêmica?  [2o sem de 2020]", multiple="dodge", palette = "Blues", ax = ax);
plt.xlabel("2o sem 2020")

ax = f.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
sns.despine(f)
sns.histplot(data = data , x = "A pandemia afetou a sua performance acadêmica?  [1o sem de 2021]", multiple="dodge", palette = "Blues", ax = ax);
plt.xlabel("1o sem 2021")

ax = f.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)
sns.despine(f)
sns.histplot(data = data , x = "A pandemia afetou a sua performance acadêmica?  [2o sem de 2021]", multiple="dodge", palette = "Blues", ax = ax);
plt.xlabel("2o sem 2021")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the order the values appear in the column decides the order of the x-axis of the `histplot`.

You can make the columns of the dataframe categorical, and force an order that way.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

column_names_long = ["A pandemia afetou a sua performance acadêmica?  [1o sem de 2020]",
                     "A pandemia afetou a sua performance acadêmica?  [2o sem de 2020]",
                     "A pandemia afetou a sua performance acadêmica?  [1o sem de 2021]",
                     "A pandemia afetou a sua performance acadêmica?  [2o sem de 2021]"]
column_names_short = ["1o sem de 2020", "2o sem de 2020", "1o sem de 2021", "2o sem de 2021"]

affectings = ['Melhorou', 'Piorou', 'Indiferente']

data = pd.DataFrame({c: np.random.choice(affectings, 100) for c in column_names_long})
# rename the columns, so seaborn can show them directly
data = data.rename(columns={long: short for long, short in zip(column_names_long, column_names_short)})
for column_name in column_names_short:
    data[column_name] = pd.Categorical(data[column_name], affectings)  # fix an order on each of the columns

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(12, 7))

for ax, column_name in zip(axs.flatten(), column_names_short):
    sns.histplot(data=data, x=column_name, color="dodgerblue", ax=ax)

sns.despine(fig)

plt.tight_layout()  # fit the subplots and their labels nicely
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot with ordered x-axis]

Alternatively, you could substitute the `histplot` with a `countplot`, which accepts the `order=` parameter and also lets you assign different colors to the bars:

```py
for ax, column_name in zip(axs.flatten(), column_names_short):
    sns.countplot(data=data, x=column_name, order=affectings,
                  palette=["dodgerblue", "crimson", "orange"], ax=ax)
```

[image: sns.countplot]

Comment: Yes! It does, thanks for the detailed response